# python: Iterating over array with two nested loops

Tags: python, arrays, loops

The goal of this loop is, for each `star` element (composed of x and y coords in the form of  `[int, int]` ) in the list `stars`, calculate the distance and angle to every other `star`

```
#list to store lists of distances
star_map = []

#go through each star to calculate distance from this star
for star in stars:

    print("main loop")

    sub_map = [] #list of distances from this star


    for sub_star in stars: 

        print("sub loop")

        #find distance
        dx = float(star[0]-sub_star[0])
        dy = float(star[1]-sub_star[1])

        #if distance is zero, break because it's the same star
        if(dx == 0 and dy == 0):
            break

        #otherwise get distance and angle    
        dist = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
        theta = get_theta(dx, dy)

        #add it to a list of distances from this star
        sub_map.append((dist, theta))
        print("sub loop")

    #add the list of distances from this star to the main list    
    star_map.append(sub_map)
```

What I would expect is that it prints one "main loop" followed by "sub loop" `len(stars) - 1` times. (-1 because once, the star in the inner and outer loops is the same, and I want to ignore that)

What happens is that I get this:

```
main loop
main loop
sub loop
main loop
sub loop
sub loop
main loop
sub loop
sub loop
sub loop
```

etc, etc, until the last loop, when it prints the expected number of "sub loop" lines.

ie each time, it loops through one more star.

Why is this happening, and how can I loop through every star, every time?

Edit:
The problem was that instead of using continue, I used break to stop the loop when the star in the sub loop was the same as the outer loop. Changing to continue fixed this.

Comment: Note that you have a `break` clause, also you have two "sub loop" prints. OTOH I don't think that this code should produce the output you describe anyway. Please recheck.

Comment: hi, (dx == 0 and dy == 0) should only be True once, when the star element in the outer and inner loops are the same. So I should see len(stars) - 1 "sub loop" lines.

Comment: edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `break` statement will cause the sub loop to break and revert back to the main loop when it encounters the same star. What you want is for the sub loop to *skip* this iteration. Try using `continue` instead of `break`.

Comment: Because `continue` causes the loop to *skip* that star, not exit the entire sub loop altogether and stop looking at the rest of the sub_stars. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) explain this behaviour of `break` and `continue` well.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham There are two nested loops - the issue is that using `break` kills the inner loop and reverts back to the next star in the main loop. That is the purpose of `break`. 

Try it yourself: 

for i in range(10): 
    print(i)
    for j in range(11,21): 
        if (j == 13):
            break
        else:
            print(j)

Will 13 be printed?

Comment: @Liongold, go run some code that behaves the same  and see if you see two main loop's printed without seeing a sub loop in between, it is **not** possible using the same  stars list.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham @ Liongold changing to continue fixed it for me. the problem was as @ Liongold said.

Comment: @Tim, if it did your output is wrong in the question, can you tell me how you could get two main loop's printed in a row without seeing a sub loop printed considering it is **before** the break?

Comment: The first time it loops, the star which is the same (dx==0 and dy==0) is the first, the next time, the second. I may have moved the print("sub loop") call, which would explain that (sorry)

Comment: @Tim, yep, it is literally impossible to recreate the output.